# Difference between Amazon EC2 API tools and AMI tools?

Tags: amazon-ec2

The developer tools page [here](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/Amazon-EC2?browse=1) list two set of tools for Amazon EC2

1. Amazon EC2 API tools
2. Amazon EC2 AMI tools

What are the differences between the two set of tools?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The API tools serve as the client interface to the Amazon EC2 web service. Use these tools to register and launch instances, manipulate security groups, and more
>
> The Amazon EC2 AMI Tools are command-line utilities to help bundle an Amazon Machine Image (AMI), create an AMI from an existing machine or installed volume, and upload a bundled AMI to Amazon S3.

From the definitions shown at [Developer Tools](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/Amazon-EC2?browse=1).

So, if you want to manage instances, use API tools; if you want to build and upload an AMI (Amazon Machine Image), use AMI tools.

Comment: It should be noted that the EC2 AMI tools are only for dealing with the older style instance-store (S3 based) AMIs.  The tools for the newer, more popular EBS boot AMIs are in the EC2 API tools (ec2-register, ec2-deregister, ec2-create-image).  The documentation from Amazon is not clear on this distiction.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the lines from Amazon Documentation:

The Amazon EC2 command line interface tools (also called the CLI tools) wrap the Amazon EC2 API actions. These tools are written in Java and include shell scripts for both Windows and Linux/UNIX/Mac OSX.

Note
Alternatively, you can use the AWS Command Line Interface (AWS CLI), which provides commands for a broad set of AWS products, including Amazon EC2. To get started with the AWS CLI, see the AWS Command Line Interface User Guide. For more information about the AWS CLI commands for Amazon EC2, see ec2 in the AWS Command Line Interface Reference.
Before you can use the Amazon EC2 CLI tools, you need to download them and configure them to use your AWS account. You can set up the tools on your own computer or on an Amazon EC2 instance.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/set-up-ec2-cli-windows.html

Comment: The PDF reads DEPRECATED across the front page